# Como puedo cambiar el perfil de pagos empresa por individual en Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Doy contexto. Tengo mi tipo de cuenta como personal en Google Play Console desde el 2013, pero al parecer cuando realice mi pago de desarrollador cree un perfil de pagos como empresa en la cual tengo mi nombre completo y datos personales sin percatarme de ello la he utilizado para realizar compras de aplicaciones, etc.

Ya que están registradas mis formas de pago en ese perfil. Mi problema surge que dicho perfil de pagos se vinculo con todas mis cuentas tanto de Play Console, Admob, Adsense y todo iba bien hasta que hace unos días me marco la verificación de cuenta y me solicita que suba datos de empresa en Adsense, por lo que no tengo esos datos.

Por tal motivo di de baja mis cuentas de Admob y Adsense ya que al no poder verificarme se que ya no me servirían pero no quiero perder la de Play Console. Aunque en dicho servicio lo tengo como cuenta personal seguramente cuando me toque verificar a mediados de este año como lo marcan las nuevas políticas de Google no lo podre hacer porque seguro me mostrar el formulario de solicitud de datos de empresa.

Mi pregunta es si puedo eliminar el perfil de empresa y solicitar la sustitución por un perfil individual o no eliminarlo y solo solicitar el cambio de vinculación de cuenta de perfil para play console ya que no se si se pierdan mis respectivas compras que he realizado de aplicaciones con el perfil de negocios.

De antemano gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

La cuenta, que tiene definida Google Play Console como "Cuenta primaria" u "owner account", no puede ser eliminada, lo que **debes realizar es crear una nueva cuenta de desarrollador y transferir tus aplicaciones**, este caso no se perderían las compras que se realizaron.

Pero debes revisar a detalle que es lo que necesitas y lo que podrías continuar teniendo al transferir tus apps a una nueva cuenta de desarrollador:

> **¿Qué se transferirá con la aplicación, cuando se transfiere a una diferente cuenta de desarrollador?**
>
> - **Se transfieren** todos los usuarios, estadísticas, datos, comentarios, valoraciones, **suscripciones y otros que estén relacionados con la app**.
> - Los pedidos que se creen antes de que se transfiera la aplicación permanecerán en la cuenta original. Si necesita reembolsar estos
>   pedidos, debe volver a la cuenta original o utilizar la API para
>   desarrolladores de Google Play.
> - Sus informes de exportaciones masivas, informes de ventas estimadas e informes de ganancias no se transferirán con la aplicación.
> - Las promociones no se transferirán a la cuenta de destino, pero los códigos promocionales emitidos anteriormente deberían seguir
>   funcionando.
> - Los grupos de prueba (abiertos, cerrados, de prueba interna y de uso compartido interno) no se pueden transferir entre cuentas. Deberá
>   volver a crear los grupos de prueba cerrados en su nueva cuenta y es
>   posible que los usuarios deban volver a participar en la prueba.
> - No se transferirán los permisos/configuraciones de enlace para servicios integrados. Asegúrese de actualizar la configuración y las
>   aplicaciones de su cuenta.
> - Transferiremos cualquier documentación o información que haya enviado en el pasado a la nueva cuenta de desarrollador. Esto puede
>   incluir, por ejemplo, envíos de declaraciones de políticas u otra
>   información que haya proporcionado a través de la página de contenido
>   de la aplicación (Política > Contenido de la aplicación).

Si deseas iniciar el proceso de transferencia, lo puedes realizar en el siguiente enlace:

https://play.google.com/console/developers/app-transfer